# Cannot insert data into tables on Azure Mobile App

Tags: android, azure

Sorry if I missed out anything critical in advance, I have never coded an Android app before.

I am required to integrate a small android app into my program for my campus project.

My actual project is MVC and is currently hosted on Azure, the database being Azure SQL.

I am trying to first get basic database functionality running from the app and so I have done the following:

Created a table using the code first method in my actual program.

Model:

```
public class Request
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public string RequestID {get;set;}

  public string Comments {get;set;}

  //Email of the requester
  public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

Added this table to my db and now I want to add data to it from my android app

I created the ToDoItem Mobile App using my current database. Downloaded it and tested and the ToDoItem function works as expected. I then tried to modify it based on my understanding to add to the Requests table

```
public class Requests
{
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
    private String mReqID;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("Name")
    private String mName;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("comments")
    private String mComm;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("Email")
    private String email;

    public Requests()
    {

    }
```

I also have getters and setters for all attributes.

I then tried to modify the existing Adding to add an item to my table at the same time

```
 private MobileServiceTable<ToDoItem> mToDoTable;
 private MobileServiceTable<Requests> mReqTable; //Added this line
 .....
 mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class);
 mReqTable = mClient.getTable(Requests.class); //This line too
```

In the add item method I added these lines

```
    final Requests Ritem = new Requests();

    Ritem.setmReqID("12345");
    Ritem.setEmail("zmoola@live.net");
    Ritem.setmComm("TEST");
    Ritem.setmName("Movie Name");
```

I added this method

```
public void addRequestTable(Requests item) throws  ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Requests ent = mReqTable.insert(item).get();
    }
```

And finally below this line

```
final ToDoItem entity = addItemInTable(item);
```

Called the method like so,

```
addRequestTable(Ritem);
```

I know this is a bad way of doing it but I'm just trying to see something working before continuing.

When i run the app and attempt to add an item to the list I get the error

> Error Cannot POST /tables/Requests

I would appreciate some help on what I'm doing wrong. Is this because I did not create an Easy table?

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT, this has been solved, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that you are using "DEPLOYMENT > Quickstart" to configure your mobile backend and download your client application.
[image]

**Note:**

- For Node.js backend, you could click the button for creating the Todoitem table. In order to create additional tables later, navigate to the 'Easy Tables' settings to add your new table or existing table with the same name. When adding tables via Easy Tables, it would help you to build your node.js backend for your added tables automatically. You could leverage "DEVELOPMENT TOOLS > App Service Editor (Preview)" to check your backend as follows:

[image]

- For C# backend, you need to download the backend code project, then you could follow this [tutorial](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/) for implementing the Table controller for your new added tables.

Additionally, for anonymous access, you could just access your table api via browser as follows to check its health:

[image]

For more table endpoints, you could refer to [Azure Mobile Apps Table Interface](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-13-the-http-table-interface/).

Comment: This wasn't what I wanted exactly but you did mention something that helped me get it, adding an Easy table with the existing name of a table so that it simply modifies the table, after which my method for inserting worked fine

Comment: I assumed that you are using Node.js backend. The above is my idea for troubleshooting the similar issue. You could follow the table endpoints to simulate the read/insert operations via Postman before you invoke your api via mobile client library.